# Can I use HTML geolocation to update a website with where I am located?

Tags: html, geolocation

Instead of the the location presented is based on the user I want it to update automatically based on where I am.

I could obviously hard-code it but I want it to be automated. I travel quite a bit: when I am in Egypt I want it to say something like "working in Egypt" or when I am home in NYC "working at homebase" etc.

I am not sure how to go about this, I am assuming it can be done with HTML5 and some more but I may be wrong any suggestions welcome.

Comment: It will help to generate useful responses if you can provide a bit more context. _What_, exactly, do you want to display your current location? A home page or blog, some web app you've designed, an HTML5 app on a mobile device?

Comment: I would like to add it to a current website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of ways, but they all have in common you have to send your location to `somewhere`, and that `somewhere` has to inform that location to your website visitors (or the place where you want to display it).

You can use HTML5 location api to determine your approximate location. For example, you set up a page (not the index page, but one you can authenticate to) that whenever you visit it, you inform your location to it. That's done with a simple

```
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (location) {
        console.log(location);
    });
```

For the second step, you have several ways to go:

- Use a backend server to persist that data in somewhere that's not just your notebook. That server can, in turn, store that location in a Database. Then, anyone visiting your website public page could see from where did you updated your location the last time.
- Instead of Databases, you can also use websockets to just relay your updates to whomever is visiting your website at a given moment. But that might be just too far fetched for what you need to do.
- Use a webservice API to inform others about your location. Automated foursquare checkins? Tweets, Facebook statuses? All of those approaches is unique to the given API, but most social networks allow you to build simple apps to do that.

TL / DR

Yes, you can use HTML5 to guess your approximate location. Nope, with HTML5 alone you can't tell other people where you are.